# USB Connection problem in Oneplus 2

Tags: usb, connection-issues

The computer says your device is not recognised. I have installed the latest updates. i Iried the options from developer options. But in the mobile hotspot and tethering options, usb tethering could not be done and undone. I am unable to connect oneplus 2 to computer windows 8.1

Answer (score 0):

You should Enable USB debugging on the phone:

1. In Settings > About phone, tap Build number seven times to enable
   the Developer Options.
2. In Settings > Developer Options, enable USB debugging.